# XAMPP Redirect to login window

Tags: php, sql, database, apache

I learned about database today but I have a problem with XAMPP. I can't get out of login window. Every time I enter my login and password, it displays login form again.

[image: that window]

Comment: That *should* be your database username/password pair (*root* and blank by default) - is that what you're entering?

Comment: @CD001 i yes, default is that, it i'm sure i change it to "root" as password, but it keep redirect to that login screen, no popup like "password is wrong" or something, just redirect to that login window, i really don't understand

Comment: try accessing the database using command prompt...
open cmd promt/terminal and type mysql command and hit enter

Comment: it will help you to check out the issue is regarding phpmyadmin or wrong password

Comment: thanks, i'll try, sorry for long respond, my internet suck

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your config.inc.php 
from this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```